# How to extract request payload variable to test from a GQL request payload in postman

Tags: javascript, postman, web-api-testing, postman-testcase, gqlquery

I am writing tests in postman and i am having GQL POST request, in which i need to extract the GQL variables in test to validate and write script. But i cant able to extract the GQL variables.
Is there any methods available to extract GQL variables like we have in json,
var req = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(pm.request.body)` it should show the details of the payload, if it's graphql, that will be there.

Comment: Yup, I can able to get the request payload now. Can you please suggest any methods or library to extract the GQL variables in test?